# Show the posts under the same category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hyperlink, categories

I am quite new to wordpress and blogging. I am working on a blog portal that has several blogs but they all use common categories that are listed on the main page of the website. The problem is that whichever category I choose on the main page, it shows me the page with exactly same posts. 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="category-holder list-center">
                <h5>Kategoriat</h5>
                <?php $site_url = get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' ); ?>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php $site_url; ?>/tags/?avain=<?php the_field('cat1'); ?>"><?php the_field('cat1'); ?></a><br/>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php $site_url; ?>/tags/?avain=<?php the_field('cat2'); ?>"><?php the_field('cat2'); ?></a><br/>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php $site_url; ?>/tags/?avain=<?php the_field('cat3'); ?>"><?php the_field('cat3'); ?></a><br/>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php $site_url; ?>/tags/?avain=<?php the_field('cat4'); ?>"><?php the_field('cat4'); ?></a><br/>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php $site_url; ?>/tags/?avain=<?php the_field('cat5'); ?>"><?php the_field('cat5'); ?></a>
            </div>
```

Could you please suggest some PHP function or give me any tip what I should do, where I should look for a solution for this problem?I hope that you understand that I am just a beginner and I would like to learn more about programming.
Thank you in advance!

Update: I also have a functions.php file, the part of the code that might be relevant:

```
function tag_posts() {
    global $wpdb;
    $tag = $_GET['avain'];
    $taxarr = array();
    $postarr = array();
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT blog_id FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'  AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND archived = '0'", ARRAY_A);
    array_unshift($blogs, 1); 
    foreach($blogs as $blog) {
        $wpdb->set_blog_id($blog[ 'blog_id' ]);
        $tax_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE name='$tag')");
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id FROM $wpdb->term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $tax_id");
        foreach ($post_id as $id) {
            $postarr = $id->object_id;
        }

        $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE ID IN ($postarr)");
        global $post;
        foreach ($posts as $post):setup_postdata($post); 

            '<div class="post"><header class="post-header"><div class="date-holder"><span>'.the_time('F jS, Y').'</span></div>';
            '<a href="'.$post->guid.'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></header>';
            '<div class="post-content">'.the_content().'</div></div>';
        endforeach;
    }
}
```

Comment: "where I should look for a solution for this problem?" - Here: http://codex.wordpress.org/  Honestly, if you're new to both Wordpress AND coding, you've a lot of learning ahead of you. You need to read, code, test, fail, read, code, test, fail, read, code, test, success! Then ask specific questions when you're stuck ;) (Someone might answer this question directly, however, but defo do some reading)

Comment: Have you seen the generated HTML and made sure the links are well formed and working if you request them directly from your browser's address bar?

Comment: @AlejandroArbiza the link on the address bar corresponds to the name of the link that I press, but the output on the page is always same

Comment: @user3125917 In that case, if the links are correct but the results aren't, the problem is elsewhere. Where exactly is hard to say with the information in hand I'm afraid.

Comment: @AlejandroArbiza I have a functions.php file and there is the code that is supposed to give a set of posts as an output, I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at this loop here:

```
foreach ($post_id as $id) {
    $postarr = $id->object_id;
}

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE ID IN ($postarr)");
```

It seems to be that the expected value for `$postarr` at the moment you query for posts is an array having post IDs. However, when you do `$postarr = $id->object_id;` you are overwriting the variable assigning to it **only the last** ID in the result set and the result is an integer variable instead of an array.

So I would suggest something like this instead:

```
foreach ($post_id as $id) {
    $postarr[] = $id->object_id; 
}

$postsAsCommaSepString = implode( ',', $postarr ); 

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE ID IN ($postsAsCommaSepString)");
```

First we are adding entries to the `$postarr`, note the brackets:

```
 $postarr[] = $id->object_id;
```

Then, since we can't use an array variable as if it was a string, we need to create a string as a comma separated list of IDs to use in the SQL `IN`. For this, we implode the array into a string using commas as separator:

```
$postsAsCommaSepString = implode( ',', $postarr );
```

Finally, we use this new string variable in the query:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE ID IN ($postsAsCommaSepString)");
```

This should solve the problem of fetching the same posts every time.

**EDIT: Bad query:**

There is also a problem in this query:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT blog_id FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE blog_id != {$wpdb->blogid} AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'  AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND archived = '0'", ARRAY_A);
```

In SQL, the *not equal* operator goes like this `<>` instead of `!=`. Please, see the corrected form below:

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT blog_id FROM {$wpdb->blogs} WHERE blog_id <> {$wpdb->blogid} AND site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'  AND spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND archived = '0'", ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but this didn't fix the problem. Should I maybe write some function which would choose the category based on its name?

Comment: @user3125917 Please, note that I changed my original answer to approach the problem based on the new information you provided.

Comment: Is it the exact same output as before or has something changed?

Comment: it changed only for one category and still it is not correct. Could the problem be because of incorrect query?

Comment: It could be: I just realized about an syntax issue in the firs query, updates in the answer.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I am using MySQL, I guess in that case this is not a mistake, is it?

Comment: If you mean the not equal operator, the correct way is `<>` in MySQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps. This may help you.

1. Create a new menu in `Dashboard` > `Appearance` > `Menus`.
2. Add categories in to the menu.
3. Use the function `wp_nav_menu()` to display the menu.
4. The category link in the menu displayed will direct you to the corresponding category page.

Please note that the category link direct you to the corresponding category page if and only if there exists `category.php` page in your themes folder.

Comment: I added some code to my post, hope this is what you mean!

Comment: Ok, fine. Did you try the way i suggests?

Comment: the problem is that my theme supports only one menu, and I would like to use the links, is it even possible?

Comment: You can add multiple menu positions and menus in WordPress. You can use the link too.